# Variables don't seem to be working inside of the function in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, variables, scope

I have a logging function in my script however when I call the function it seems to work properly except for the actual logging portion. It echos to the screen just fine, but when I go to check the log file it doesn't update. Below is the code.

```
Function Get-Logger { 
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [String]$message,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
       [validatescript({[enum]::getvalues([system.consolecolor]) -contains $_})][string]$Color
    )

    ### Function Variables ###
    $Log = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ToString().Replace(".ps1",".log")
    $LogPath = "C:\Source\Scripts\ScriptLog" 
    $LogFile = "$LogPath\$Log" 
    $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss"

    #Creates the ScriptLog folder in C:\Source\Scripts if it doesn't exist
    IF(-not(Test-Path $LogPath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $LogPath
        Get-Logger "Created ScriptLog Directory"
    } 

    Write-Host $TimeStamp -NoNewline
    IF ($Color) {
        Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor $($color)
    } Else {
        Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor Cyan
        }       

    $logMessage = "[$TimeStamp]  $message"
    $logMessage | Out-File -Append -LiteralPath $LogFile


}
```

The variables are only used within the function, if I place the variables outside of the function it works, but I want to try and keep the variables within the function itself.

I've tried adding scopes as well `$global:`, `$script:`, `$local:`, etc.. and none of that seems to work. Is it possible to actually have the variables stay within the function, or do I have to place them outside the function?

Comment: `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` will resolve to `Get-Logger` - check if there isn't a `C:\Source\Scripts\ScriptLog\Get-Logger` file on disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are always visible in the same scope (and all descendant scopes, unless created with the `$private:` scope specifier), so they aren't the problem.

However, **it looks like your intent is to base the `$Log` variable value on the *script-level* definition of `$MyInvocation`, not the *function's* (which reflects how the *function* was invoked).**

To refer to the *script*'s definition of `$MyInvocation` - from which you can derive the *script file name* as intended - use the `$script:` scope specifier:

```
$Log = $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.ToString().Replace(".ps1",".log")
```

More simply, however, you can use the [automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables?view=powershell-7#pscommandpath), which contains the script's full file path, even inside functions:

```
$Log = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($PSCommandPath) + '.log'
```

In PowerShell [Core] 6+, you can alternatively use `Split-Path -LeafBase` (not supported in Windows PowerShell):

```
$Log = (Split-Path -LeafBase $PSCommandPath) + '.log'
```

Finally, for the sake of completeness, the function's own `$MyInvocation` variable has a `.PSCommandPath` *property* that too reflects the full script path:

```
$Log = (Split-Path -LeafBase $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath) + '.log'
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I followed your first suggestion of adding the ``script:`` infront of the ``$myInvocation`` and that worked perfectly... and upon closer looking I see the log file named after the function which shows the mistake! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Fitzgery; my pleasure.